# Password regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

Password must contain five (5) capital letters, six (6) symbols and two hyphens (-) in any order.

I've wrote this regexp, but it doesnt work.

```
const passwordRegexp = /^[A-Z]{5}[!@#$%^&*]{5}[/-]{2}$/g;
console.log(passwordRegexp.test('FG-FGB-@$%^*'));
```

Comment: With `must contain` do you mean **exactly** five (5) capital letters, six (6) symbols and two hyphens (-) in any order, or **at least**

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is trying to match those conditions *in order*, so something like `ABCDE!@!@!--` will match, but that's obviously not what you want.

If you're determined to use regular expressions for this purpose (which might not be the best option), you can try to combine [positive lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with non-capturing groups, like this:

`^(?=.{12}$)(?=(?:[!@#$%^&*-]*[A-Z]){5})(?=(?:[A-Z-]*[!@#$%^&*]){5})(?=(?:[A-Z!@#$%^&*]*[-]){2}).*$`

Here's a more [practical explanation](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Comment: It is unclear though, because your question says that there should be 6 symbols, and your example and string to match show that you need 5. Whatever the actual case, just fix the total password length in the first group (if all conditions require "at least" and not "exactly" N characters, just remove it altogether) and length of the second group that matches `!@#$%^&*`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex basically says: i require five letters, then five special characters, then two slashes or dashes. Exactly in that order.
That's probably not what you want.